# How to do graph union and intersection in ArangoDB AQL

Tags: graph, arangodb, aql

We have a graph model(not data) like the image below:

[image]

The actual graph that stores data has only one `vertex collection` and an `edge collection`

How to do a union(or) and intersection(and) query on multiple path result on a vertex:

```js
countries -> cities -> users -> like songs 
                             -> read books
```

union query on user vertices:

```js
return all paths that each user has at least one path on any branch

usa -> chicago -> john -> book-1 (accepted)
usa -> chicago -> john -> song-1 (accepted)

germany -> cologne -> john -> book-1 (accepted)
```

intersect query on user vertices:

```js
return all paths that each user has at least one path on each branch

usa -> chicago -> john -> book-1 (accepted)
usa -> chicago -> john -> song-1 (accepted)

germany -> cologne -> john -> book-1 (not accepted)
```

About intersection we need complex intersections where we have a hierarchy of intersections where each intersection on a vertex will operate on the result of other intersection on another vertex down the path.

About union I came up with this query, is this the correct way to do union in AQL:

```js
for vertex in Vertex
for v,e,p in 1..3 any vertex._id graph 'DataGraph'
OPTIONS {bfs: true, uniqueVertices: 'global'}
FILTER

(
p.edges[0].edgeCollectionCode == 'locatedin'
and p.edges[1].edgeCollectionCode == 'livein'
and p.edges[2].edgeCollectionCode == 'read'
and length(p.edges)==3
)
||
(
p.edges[0].edgeCollectionCode == 'locatedin'
and p.edges[1].edgeCollectionCode == 'livein'
and p.edges[2].edgeCollectionCode == 'like'
and length(p.edges)==3
)

return p
```

Comment: When you say that you only have one vertex collection do you mean that you are putting all that data (songs, users , books, etc) in just one collection? If that is the case I would advise that you reconsider the approach. Unless you have very little data and a few user, you will run into performance issues at some point with all the data in one place. Coming back to your question, take a look at these examples which hopefully will cover most of your cases https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/cookbook/graph-example-actors-and-movies.html

Comment: Thanks @camba1, yes I'm aware of using multiple collection for performance reasons. thanks for cookbook link, it was very useful to see how ArangoDB team suggests union/intersection, But I need more complex intersection which I think is different from what they are trying to do.